# With Goosle Apps Script, how to write 2D-array on SpreadSheet with aspect length-to-width ratio of 12 to 2

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I would to have ideas with GAS codes from you.
I could not get my ideal output like below

(My Ideal)
Both Headlines and URLs go tandemly (I mean Column A and B have them respectively)

However, my current output goes below:
Both go horizontally.　(I mean Row 1 and 2 have them respectively)
| Headline1 | Headline2 | Headline3 |
|-----------|-------|-----------|
|URL_1|URL_2|URL_3|

```
function jijiPress() {
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=ind");
  let text = response.getContentText("utf-8");
  let biz_article = Parser.data(text).from('class="textL">').to('</ul>').build();
  topics = Parser.data(biz_article).from('<a').to('</a>').iterate();
  let dt = new Date();
  let now = new Date();
  let y = dt.getFullYear();
  let m = ("00" + (dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
  let d = ("00" + (dt.getDate())).slice(-2);
  let h = now.getHours();
  let mm = now.getMinutes();
  let filename = y+m+d+h+mm + "_jiji_articles";
  let Title = new Array();
  let URL = new Array();


  for(news of topics){

      //Get URLs
      let newsUrl = news.replace(/.*href="/,"").replace(/".*/,"");
      newsUrl = "https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=ind"+newsUrl
      URL.push(newsUrl);
      //Get Headlines
      let newsTitle = news.replace(/href[^>]*>/,"")
      Title.push(newsTitle);
  }

  let dTitle =[Title];
  dTitle.push(URL);
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(filename);


// The code below works, but is not my ideal.(please see myIdeal.xlsx) 
  let sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,dTitle.length,dTitle[0].length).setValues(dTitle);


  dTitle.push(URL);
  Logger.log(dTitle);
  Logger.log("did it!");  
}
```

Any comments are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I forgot to erase this sentense: "please see myIdeal.xlsx". Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change as I have shown.

1st, don't use `new Array()` use the array literal `[]` its faster.

2nd, I create an array `URL`.  Then push each item `newUrl` and `newTitle` into it.  I then push `URL` into `results` which makes it a 2D array.

```
let results = [];

for(news of topics){
  let URL = [];
  //Get URLs
  let newsUrl = news.replace(/.*href="/,"").replace(/".*/,"");
  newsUrl = "https://jen.jiji.com/jc/eng?g=ind"+newsUrl
  URL.push(newsUrl);
  //Get Headlines
  let newsTitle = news.replace(/href[^>]*>/,"")
  URL.push(newsTitle);
  results.push(URL)
}

let ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(filename);
let sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,results.length,2).setValues(results);
Logger.log(results);
```